Proving that a function with only removable discontinuities can be made continuous
I'm working with Spivak's "Calculus" and was doing the following problem:

Let $f$ be a function with the property that every discontinuity is a removable discontinuity. This means that $\lim_{y\to x}f(y)$ exists for all $x$. Let $g(x):= \lim_{y\to x}f(y)$. Prove that $g$ is continuous.

I don't have access to the solution's manual at the moment, so I'm not sure of the proof given by Spivak. However, after thinking for a while, I came up with the following proof (which, if correct, I'm pretty sure is a huge overkill since the proof shouldn't be so long). In this proof, I use the fact that you can find a punctured neighbourhood around every point for which f is continuous. I wanted to know whether this specific argument is correct and, if not, why does my reasoning for it fail in the proof? For this proof, I've made use of the local property of limits, which can be framed as the following:
$$\text{If there exists}\;\delta\;\text{s.t.}\;|x - a| < \delta\implies f(x) = g(x)\;\text{then}\;\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$$
Proof:
Let $x_0$ be an arbitrary point. My general strategy is to show that if for all points the limit exists (which is the case for $f$), you can find a range around every point such that the function is continuous for every point in this range. So, since $x_0$ is an arbitrary point, I want to show that I can find a range $|x-x_0| < \delta$ such that $\lim_{y\to x}f(y) = f(x)$ provided that $x\neq x_0$. If this is true, then $f(x) = g(x)$ for $|x-x_0| < \delta$ (except $x_0$). Then, use the local property of limits to show that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) = g(x_0) = \lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)$.
So, all I have to show is that there exists a $\delta$ such that $|x - x_0| < \delta\implies \lim_{y\to x}f(y) = f(x)$.
Since every point has a limit, there exists a $\delta_1$ such that $|x - x_0| < \delta_1\implies |f(x) - L_1| < \epsilon$ (call this statement $S_1$). Furthermore, the limit exists at $x$. Therefore, $|y - x| < \delta_2\implies |f(y) - L_2| < \epsilon$ (call this statement $S_2$). We'll be done if it can be showed that $L_2 = f(x)$.
To link $S_1$ and $S_2$, we must further constraint $y$ so that it is also within $(x_0-\delta_1,x_0+\delta_1)$. This can be done by defining $\delta_3 = min(\delta_2,x-(x_0-\delta_1),(x_0+\delta_1)-x)$. Now, $|y - x| < \delta_3\implies |f(y) - L_2|$. For such a $y$, since it is within $\delta_1$ of $x_0$, we can say that $|y - x_0| < \delta_1\implies |f(y) - L_1| < \epsilon$ (call this statement $S_3$).
Finally, use $S_1$ and $S_2$ in conjunction. Notice that $|y - x + x - x_0| = |y - x_0|\leq |y - x| + |x - x_0|$. But, $|y - x| < \delta_2$ and $|x - x_0| < \delta_1\implies |y - x| + |x - x_0| < \delta_1 + \delta_2$. Therefore, $|y - x_0| \leq |y - x| + |x - x_0| < \delta_1 + \delta_2$. So, $|x - x_0| < \delta_1, |y - x| < \delta_2\implies |y-x_0| < \delta_1+\delta_2$.
Furthermore, $|x - x_0| < \delta_1, |y - x| < \delta_2\implies |f(x) - L_1| < \epsilon, |f(y) - L_2| < \epsilon$. But, $|f(x) - L_1| < \epsilon\implies |f(x) - L_1| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}, |f(y) - L_2| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. This further implies that $|f(x) - L_1 + f(y) - L_2|\leq |f(x) - L_1| + |f(y) - L_2| < \epsilon$. Therefore, $|x - x_0| < \delta_1, |y - x| < \delta_2\implies |y - x_0| < \delta_1 + \delta_2\land |f(x) - L_1 + f(y) - L_2| < \epsilon$.
Thus, $\lim_{y\to x_0} f(y) = L_2 + L_1 - f(x)$. However, by $S_3$, $\lim_{y\to x_0} f(y) = L_1$. Since a limit cannot be different values, $f(x) = L_2$. QED
EDIT EXPLANATION: According to @XanderHenderson my question does not meet the requirements of the solution verification tag because I'm not asking verification for a specific piece of my argument. So, now, I'm explicitly asking for someone to verify the "specific argument" that you can find a punctured neighbourhood around every point for which f is continuous. If not, kindly point out why my reasoning fails.

As explained in the answer by @empy2 if $x_0$ is a point of discontinuity of $f,$ any punctured $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\setminus {x_0}$ may contain other points of discontinuity. In the example every nonzero rational number is a point of discontinuity, hence discontinuities concentrate. I am unable to spot the place with  mistake in your argument as it is too long. Perhaps empy2 can take the effort of finding it.

This is not an appropriate use of the [tag:solution-verification] tag.  Per the information provided by clicking on the tag description, questions with this tag need to highlight a specific part of an argument which is problematic.  You need to focus on a particular problem---we are not here to grade homework (whether this is homework or not, you are essentially asking the community here to grade your work).

@XanderHenderson if you read the conversation in the comments of the answer by empy2, it's clear that the "specific part of an argument" that you're looking for is whether it's true that you can find a punctured neighbourhood around every point for which f is continuous. I'll make this change in the question if you want me to satisfy the requirements of the solution verification tag. Otherwise I don't see why my question is invalid (also this is not homework, I'm a high schooler interested in math)

I have spotted the place in your proof which is invalid in my opinion and included an explanation at the begining of my answer.

The claim
$$\lim_{y\to x_0}f(y)=L_2+L_1-f(x)$$ is not justified. It requires that for given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$|y-x_0|<\delta \implies |f(y)-L_2-L_1+f(x)|<\varepsilon$$ In the OP proof we take $\delta=\delta_1+\delta_2.$
In order to get the estimate by $\varepsilon$ we need $0<|y-x|<\delta_2$ and $0<|x-x_0|<\delta_1.$ However these two conditions are not  guarranted by $0<|y-x_0|<\delta_1+\delta_2.$
In short,  $x$ is fixed at the begining of the proof. If $y$ is close to $x_0,$ for example $|y-x_0|< {1\over 2}|x-x_0|,$ then $y$ cannot be close to $x,$ as we always have $|y-x|\ge |x-x_0|-|y-x_0|> {1\over 2}|x-x_0|.$
Fix $x_0.$ We want to show that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)= g(x_0).$  Fix $\varepsilon>0.$ There is $\delta_0>0$ such that  for $$0<|t-x_0|<\delta_0\implies |f(t)-g(x_0)|<{\varepsilon\over 2}\quad (*)$$ Fix $x$ so that $0<|x-x_0|<\delta_0.$ There exists $t_x$ so that $t_x\neq x,$ $0<|t_x-x_0|<\delta$  and $|f(t_x)-g(x)|<{\varepsilon\over 2}.$ Hence, by $(*),$ we get $|f(t_x)-g(x_0)|<{\varepsilon\over 2}.$ Therefore
$$|g(x)-g(x_0)|\le |g(x)-f(t_x)|+|f(t_x)-g(x_0)|<{\varepsilon\over 2}+{\varepsilon\over 2}=
\varepsilon$$

your statement is true, but I don't really assume that $0 < |y - x_0| < \delta_1 + \delta_2$ imply that $0 < |y - x| < \delta_2$ and $0 < |x - x_0| < \delta_1$. I've edited my proof to clearly show my line of reasoning. Thanks

I have extended my explanation. The main point is that you fix $x$ at the begining of the proof and then concentrate on $y$ which are close to $x.$ Such $y$ cannot be located arbitrarily close to $x_0.$ For instance when $y_0=x-\eta (x-x_0)$ with $\eta<{1\over 2}$ we have $|y_0-x_0|=(1-\eta)|x-x_0|>{1\over 2}|x-x_0|.$

Your proof tries to show that $f$ is continuous near every point of discontinuity.  But here is one where it is not.
Take the function where $f(x)=0$ for irrational $x$, and $f(p/q)=1/q$ for rational numbers.  Then $\lim_{y\to x}f(y)=0$ for every $x$.  You can make $f(x)$ continuous at $x=p/q$ by replacing just $f(p/q)$ with $0$, so every discontinuity is removeable, but it is still discontinuous at every other rational point except $x=0$.
EDIT
Once you have chosen $\epsilon$ and $\delta_1$, you can't prove that $f(y)-f(x)$ is any smaller than that $\epsilon$.  So you can't show $\lim_{y\to x}f(y)=f(x)$.  You can shrink $\epsilon$, but then you have to shrink $\delta_1$, and $x$ may no longer be in the interval.

I'm not saying Spivak's question is wrong.

@Empy2 I agree with RyszardSzwarc. If you're saying that the limit of f at all points is zero, then, by definition of g, g(x) = 0 for all points, thereby making it continuous

Now I see the intention. The OP proof is based on the wrong concept. (+)

@RyszardSzwarc could you please point out what part of my proof is wrong?

It is explained in this answer. Your claim "you can find a range around every point such that the function is continuous for every point in this range" is wrong.

@RyszardSzwarc yes I read that, but where in proving this statement have I made a mistake?

@RyszardSzwarc also this statement excludes the original point. So, I'm saying that around an arbitrary point $x_0$ I can find a neighbourhood where f is continuous excluding $x_0$
